# Using Font Awesome in Kendo Grid buttons with CSS

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, font-awesome

I want to use Font Awesome for certain buttons inside Kendo Grids.

I can use the `HtmlAttributes` to add the class and it works fine.

```
command.Custom("name").Text(" ").Click("handler").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fa fa-file-text" });
```

But to avoid repetition, I'd like to use CSS. Kendo Grid add a class with the name of the custom button to it, e.g. `k-grid-name`. The end DOM looks like this:

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-name" href="#"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> </a>
```

The CSS selector that I'm trying is:

```
.k-grid-name{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f000";
}
.k-grid-name a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f000";
}
.k-grid-name span{
    background-color: red;
}
```

I prefer to use the inside `span`, because it's in the center of the button. What's the correct `selector` for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.k-grid-custombtnname span:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f00c";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Replace "custombuttonname" with the name of the custom grid button.

```
.k-grid-content .k-button.k-grid-custombuttonname::before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
    content: "\f000" !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here' my solution.  Register the dataBound callback with this..

```
    const dataBound =(e) => {
        $(".k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-custombtnname ").append("<span title='View Request'><i class='fas fa-search'></i></span>");
    }
```